# How to handle 2 While Loops at the same time in C

Tags: c

Im working on a simple chat programm for a school project.
The problem with the chat is that you have to make an input before the chat partner can send anything.

Here is my code:

```
while(1)
{
    //Die Buffer bei jedem Durchlauf leeren
    memset(&message, 0, sizeof(message));
    memset(&sendbuf, 0, sizeof(message));
    memset(&recvbuf, 0, sizeof(recvbuf));     


    //Daten an den Client senden
    gets(message);
    strcat(sendbuf, serverAddon);
    strcat(sendbuf, message);

    if ((send(client, sendbuf, 256, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Fehler beim senden der Nachricht.\n");
        closesocket(sock);
        closesocket(client);
        WSACleanup();
        trennlinie();
        system("pause");
        exit(3);
    }


    //Daten vom Client empfangen
    if ((recv(client, recvbuf, 256, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Empfangen der Nachricht fehlgeschlagen.\n");
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        trennlinie();
        system("pause");
        exit(5);
    }
    printf("%s\n",recvbuf);

}
```

I hope you understand my problem.
Do I have to use threads to handle the send/recv at the same time?

Comment: You should or must use threads to handle this

Comment: multi-threading

Comment: Standard C does not have any non-blocking user input operations. Use threads

Comment: A better solution would be to use non-blocking I/O that way you avoid the problems that come with threads.

Comment: regarding: `gets(message);`  The function `gets()` had been depreciated for decades and completely removed since about 2009.

Comment: suggest using the `select()` function